Error: Invalid bool: 142
Recently I usually got this error, when fetch or getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount or send tx to solana devnet
Error: Invalid bool: 142
    at WrappedLayout.decodeBool [as decoder] (repo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/node_modules/@coral-xyz/borsh/src/index.ts:188:9)
    at WrappedLayout.decode (repo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/node_modules/@coral-xyz/borsh/src/index.ts:111:17)
    at Structure.decode (repo/node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1234:32)
    at Sequence.decode (repo/node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1090:34)
    at Structure.decode (repo/node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1234:32)
    at WrappedLayout.decode (repo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/node_modules/@coral-xyz/borsh/src/index.ts:111:37)
    at Structure.decode (repo/node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1234:32)
    at BorshAccountsCoder.decodeUnchecked (repo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/coder/borsh/accounts.ts:85:19)
    at BorshAccountsCoder.decode (repo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/coder/borsh/accounts.ts:63:17)
    at AccountClient.fetchNullableAndContext (repo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/account.ts:164:34)

const { vaultAta: usdtPool0VaultAta } = await getTokenAccounts(
    provider,
    usdtPool0Asset,
    boostedMasterWombatProgram.globalState
  );

import {
  Account,
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  mintTo,
  transfer,
  getMint,
  Mint
} from "@solana/spl-token";
export async function getTokenAccounts(
  provider: anchor.Provider,
  token: PublicKey,
  vault?: PublicKey,
  user?: PublicKey
) {
  const userAta = user
    ? await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        provider.connection,
        defaultWallet,
        token,
        user
      )
    : await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        provider.connection,
        defaultWallet,
        token,
        defaultWallet.publicKey,
        false
      );

  const vaultAta = vault
    ? await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        provider.connection,
        defaultWallet,
        token,
        vault,
        true
      )
    : undefined;
  return { userAta, vaultAta };
}

is there any problem with solana devnet RPC? I have replaced it to helius rpc but still got the same error

Could you share your rpc call?

I have used this RPC: https://api.devnet.solana.com
And also tried one from helius, and it fail even I try a func from spl-token
getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount

Can you update the question with your code?

Yes, I have updated
